# How to call thread for any function in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

please help me on this how to start thread on background in iphone on every when application is start for 
 in my sqlite database table i have one column sync status .there i have 3 value 0,1,3.i have to call these values on database table.0 means if application has synced data to server.if any data in my database is updated the sync status changes to 1 and 3 means data is being send to server i.e syncing is in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Create the request.

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]
                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                timeoutInterval:60.0];
// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
// Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
// receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
// Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
```

Then implement delegate methods of NSURLConnection

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
// Append the new data to receivedData.
// receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
if(!receivedData){
   receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}
[receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
// release the connection, and the data object
[connection release];
// receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
[receivedData release];

// inform the user
NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
      [error localizedDescription],
      [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
// do something with the data
// receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

// release the connection, and the data object
[connection release];
[receivedData release];
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @jigneshBrahmkhatri can u give some explanation how can i do this please help me on this i not understand what u try to tell me in detail

Comment: @jigneshBrahmkhatri but i want to check in database where the status change or not if any value change then value should 1and should sync to server database

Comment: you can create request only if status = 0

Comment: @jigneshBrahmkhatri but 0means no value should send to server i have to check value with 1,3 for sending the data to server please see my question what i want as par my question friend

Comment: but status value logic is upto yours, I already asked that do you want to request to server in thread? and now you need to apply your logic that when should call request

Comment: hi are u there i need a help ur in sqlite

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSThread class method to start the new thread.e.g.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(newThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];



///////

-(void)newThread{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   ///your code

   [pool release];

}
```

for more read [Thread Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i)

Answer (score 0):

starting threads in background easily done with NSInvocation, all you need to know is [here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/)

there is GCD but each to their own